# Deploy chatbot to AzureFunction

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, data-science, chatbot

Im trying to deploy Chatbot to Azure Function.

Im using vs code to deploy to code and also debugging with Azure Tools and Azurite. Locally everything is working.
After deploying a got this error:

```cs
 " import duckdb ImportError: generic_type: type "ExplainType" is already registered"
```

So i tried to remove the duckdb, but when i remove the duckdb library i got this error:

```cs
"import duckdb ImportError: initialization failed"
```

It is a part of code where langchain should parse docs to create index.

Python 3.9.0 and these libraries

- azure-functions
- langchain
- duckdb
- chromadb==0.3.29
- pandas
- openai
- tiktoken
- unstructured
- python-magic
- tabulate
- pdf2image
- pytesseract&
  Local: WIN 10 and venv

Thx for advice and help

Tried multiple version of libraries.

Comment: Please provide your code if possible (excluding sensitive information).

Answer (score 0):

> " import duckdb ImportError: generic_type: type "ExplainType" is already registered"

This could be because of the conflict between the dependencies or trying to import the `duckdb` package multiple times in your application

- Try uninstalling `duckdb` package and install again using the below commands:

```py
pip uninstall duckdb
pip install duckdb
```

[image]
[image]

(or)

- Remove or uninstall all the dependencies you have in your project, add them in `requirements.txt` .

[image]

Install all the dependencies again by running `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

[image]